github runner produce unreliable executables when using unique_lock<std::mutex>
I'm facing a serious issue when deploying executables built by Windows GitHub runners: any executable that uses std::unique_lock<std::mutex> is unreliable! It compiles correctly, but will unexpectedly fail at runtime.
The "hello mutex" program below will produce a perfectly valid executable, when compiled on a standard windows machine.
#include "stdio.h"
#include <future>

int main()
{
    printf("main enter\n");
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    printf("Created mutex\n");
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    printf("Instantiated lock\n");
    printf("main exit\n");
}

However, when downloading and running the exe produced by GitHub runners, the program will fail when creating the lock (it will exit or hang after printing "Created mutex").
I created a super simple repository on GitHub to demonstrate the issue: https://github.com/pthom/poub_pfd
Executables produced by GitHub runners can be found inside the artifacts of this repository: https://github.com/pthom/poub_pfd/actions
This issue did bite me hard... I discovered it 1 month after the release of my Python / Pybind11 library (for which I deploy multiple native wheels directly from GH Runners artifacts)

I have several related questions:

Did I make an obvious mistake?

Did anyone encounter this issue also?


I'm almost sure that I am not the only one who might suffer from this, since this is almost a Hello World program using mutexes.
I'm certain that this issue is present since July 3rd, since it was discovered much later in a release of a python library which I produced at this date.

Does anyone know if this issue or a related one was already posted to GitHub?
If not, where is the best location where I should post it?


How certain are you that your version(s) of Windows are forward-compatible with whatever version Github is using as "windows-latest"?

I'd guess that the GitHub runner is using a more recent version of visual studio than the version of the runtime redistributables you've installed

Thanks! It works with windows-2019 runners, but fails with windows-2022 runners.  The fact that the executable starts and happily loads an incompatible CRT is incomprehensible IMHO.
